# Valid HTML and semantics

Tags: discussion, design, markdown, semantics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use an HTML Validator on SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23178/use-an-html-validator-on-so)

Does SO family care about valid html markup and semantic web? I've noticed that tables are used in most places where non-tabular data is being displayed.

Comment: Remember that even div and span tags have a specific place in a semantic layout. They're not the generic tags people seem to think there. So if you have to use a dozen un-semantic divs to acheive a layout you can describe more easily and clearly with one or two tables, which is better? –

Answer (score 3):

Apparently we can safely say that valid HTML markup [isn't](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com) their top priority.

Then again, I for one would *not* blame the developers for focusing their efforts more on the functionality and user experience of the sites...

Edit: even if strict standards compliance doesn't seem to be of utmost importance, they clearly *do* care about accessibility and interoperability, as the SO family sites work reasonably well with most (or all) of commonly used browsers.

Comment: i think they work well cause of table layout. IMHO there should be technical designers who should work only on markup and client-side programming.

Comment: If that's the case, one has to wonder if it would really make sense to move away from table layout. Better interoperability has value in itself, but I'm not so sure if that's true for getting rid of tables. About the second point: dev resources are expensive, and I believe only Jeff et al are in the position of making an informed decision about how to best allocate them in such a small team.

Comment: That validation report is actually fairly good if I must say so myself. They used meta tags without including their deceleration files, but other than that, it's good.