# Why isn't the main Stack Overflow site fully W3C standards compliant?

Tags: discussion, design, performance, yslow

The [W3C validator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W3C_Markup_Validation_Service) reports errors when the Stack Overflow homepage is run through it.

Simple fixes, like wrapping [`CDATA`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA) sections inside scripts, get around a lot of errors.

Does the team use any tools like [YSlow](http://yslow.org/)? It looks as though JavaScript and CSS aren't minified, script references are not at the bottoms of pages, etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23178/use-an-html-validator-on-so

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why isn’t the main SO site fully W3C
>   standards compliant?

Because it works for all intent and purposes even if it's not. That's all that matters, right?

> Simple fixes like wrapping CDATA
>   sections inside the script gets round
>   a lot of errors.

CDATA is XHTML. Stack Overflow uses HTML.

> Do the authors use any tools like
>   ySlow? It looks as though javascript
>   and css isn't minified, script
>   references are not at the bottom etc.

[They](http://sstatic.net/mso/all.css?v=6638) [are](http://sstatic.net/mso/js/master.js?v=6523). Scripts at the bottom won't really speed up the loading of the page in a noticeable fashion; many popular websites including wikipedia have them at the top.

Comment: The very few errors on the Stack overflow page could indeed be fixed by wrapping the JavaScript code into CDATA tags. http://htmlhelp.com/tools/validator/problems.html#script and I too would be interested to know whether there's a special reason behind that.

Comment: @Pekka: SO uses HTML, not XHTML.

Comment: @BalusC is using `CDATA` limited to XML? Correct me if I'm wrong, but that would be new to me. I have been using it merrily in HTML for years, and as far as I know, it is both best practice and valid standard to wrap script content into CDATA tags to prevent the validator from validating actual JavaScript string data (which is happening here).

Comment: @Pekka: I knew the same (that CDATA is XHTML-only). With HTML you have to escape the closing brace: `<\/test>`.

Comment: @Pekka: either you actually used XHTML or you didn't revalidate after adding CDATA (it would still error on it!). Escaping the closing brace as Kop commented is indeed the right way in HTML.

Comment: @BalusC @Kop dang, you are right! en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cdata  I stand corrected.

Comment: You can use `//<![CDATA[` in HTML, but it doesn't do anything. The content of `<script>` and `<style>` is already CDATA, in which the only invalid character sequence is the `</` (ETAGO) token that should according to SGML rules end the element (though in fact that's not what browsers do).

Answer (score 5):

- JavaScript code and CSS is in fact minified
- [W3C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Wide_Web_Consortium) says we're valid -- http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://stackoverflow.com

The only invalid piece comes from the ad server.

Comment: Fair point :) Although not too important, I was referring to the inline script blocks not being minified (that would be a challenge though!).