# What does the % in the Community Wiki box mean?

Tags: support, community-wiki

This question is about the **community wiki info-box** in the bottom right corner of questions: **What does the percent number refer to?**

The example quoted is the [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

> [image]

And do I get the rest right?

1. The question was reviewed/edited 95 times
2. 51 users were involved
3. The percent number I can't assign
4. Last editor (here: sbi)

Comment: I think it's the amount contributed by the author with the most contributions, which is the one shown in that author box (@sbi in the C++ books question). See the [description](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki): `Additionally, community wiki posts show the editor with the highest percentage of the remaining post in the current version in the author field`

Comment: @Mureinik what is a revived question? :)

Comment: @Mureinik no worry, happens even to [SE employees](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296609/no-advertisements-on-despite-having-less-than-200-rep-mobile-theme/296611?noredirect=1#comment962547_296611)... :-D

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> 4. Last editor

It's not the last editor, it's the *most prolific* editor, based on a very naive calculation involving lines of the post that were changed.

The percentage is the amount of content attributed to that editor, so in this case it's saying that sbi's content is responsible for 23% of the visible post.

Answer (score 10):

It's a rough measure of the percentage contributed to the post by the editor that made the largest contribution to the question.

(say that five times fast)

Comment: I can't. It's too long to fit in the comment box.

Comment: I just did. And I am sitting in a library. I think we could call it brain jam... :-D