# No advertisements on despite having less than 200 rep? (mobile theme)

Tags: support, mobile-web, privileges, advertising

The privilege for 200 reputation is [See reduced ads](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads). I'm fairly sure that I'm remembering correctly that there was no ads when I had lower than 200 rep, so what does that privilege mean?

Note: I'm browsing from mobile using the mobile theme of the site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means you won't see advertisements **inside questions**, e.g. this one:

> [image]

There can be two of those, one on top of the question and one below the qustion when there are answers. The Reduced Ads privilege means you won't get them anymore.

Also note that ads are only enabled on few sites, not in all SE sites. Those sites are listed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/243521/152859).

The above applies only for the full site theme. The mobile theme of Stack Exchange sites **never showed those advertisements**, that's why you never saw them.

Comment: Note there's a tag [tag:mobile-web] for the question.

Comment: Also, does region matter? I'm in east Asia.

Comment: @iBug this changes everything, see my edit. As for region, it does affect, see answer by Horia.

Answer (score 2):

It *does* mean you get to see reduced ads. As the link says, the leaderboard ads don't show, though you will get sidebar ads as well as ads for jobs from our [job board](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs).

However, the ads in the leaderboard are also targeted to specific countries, or tech combinations. If you're in an area where people haven't targeted anything we won't show you anything.

I'm in the same boat as well, being based in eastern Europe. However, whenever I log in to Stack Overflow from western Europe or America, I see the standard number of ads.

Comment: Hey, just curious, why no ads in the mobile theme? With increasing numbers of people using their mobile devices for everything, I expect the advertisers might be upset by this.

Comment: It was a product decision made before my time, but it boiled down to not being enough traffic on mobile. At some point we'll definitely revisit our decision. The mobile app does have job ads for example, though just the stacked change one right now, not the stack overflow one.

Comment: Thanks. As for job ad for app, what do you mean exactly? What is "stacked change" ad? Or did you mean Stack Exchange job ad? afaik it's only part of Stack Overflow, isn't it?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Is it a typo or what do you mean by "stacked change" ad?

Comment: @ShadowWizard and iBug, yes I meant "StackExchange" but autocorrect changed it. Wrt my main point, there is a new StackOverflow mobile app, separate from the StackExchange one, and it doesn't​ yet have job ads, on account of it being so new. You can find it [here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/05/16/stack-overflow-official-app-launches-ios-android/)

Comment: @iBug yes, typo by the answer author, just wasn't sure. Horia thanks, makes sense now.

Comment: @ShadowWizard no worries, glad I could help!