# When a person chooses to make their question/answer community-wiki, does it show up on their question/answer list?

Tags: support, community-wiki

Recently, I found [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta), and it was community-wiki. When I went to the [asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/152279/nick-t)'s profile (Nick-T), the question didn't appear anywhere; it had 676 votes and his [top question that was showing up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126017/are-expletives-allowed-in-se-chat) had 35 votes, so his 676-vote question should have been on the top. I don't know why, but I'm pretty sure I recall community-wiki questions at least showing up as the author's question.

Comment: They didn't ask the question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/19478/1

Comment: @rene then why is Nick-T's profile linked like it would be if he asked it?

Comment: Well, I was afraid you were going to ask that but IIRC it has something to do with who made the most significant edits to the post. Where the algorithm can be tricked to believe a lot was changed so it chooses an unexpected editor.

Comment: Found the explanation of how the usercard works for CW posts: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190204/what-does-the-in-the-community-wiki-box-mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [@rene](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/158100/rene), I figured this out.

1. [Nick-T](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/152279/nick-t) didn't ask the question, instead, [TheTXI](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/22164/thetxi) did.
2. The only reason [Nick-T](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/152279/nick-t)'s name was there was because they were the *most prolific* editor, according to [Tim Stone](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/150235/tim-stone) when he answered [What does the % in the Community Wiki box mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190204/what-does-the-in-the-community-wiki-box-mean?noredirect=1&lq=1)